# How to retrieve crystal report page(section) name using c#

Tags: crystal-reports, sections

I have crystal report that I want to separate by the page(section) name and create a pdf file.  I've been looking everywhere and have not found and answer.  Hopefully someone can help.

`
foreach (ReportDocument pgnName in rpt)
{
exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = pdfRtfWordOpts;
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;

```
                destinationOpts.DiskFileName = "C:\\Temp\\report File" + pgnName+ ".pdf";
                exportOpts.ExportDestinationOptions = destinationOpts;
                exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                rpt.Export(exportOpts);
            }
```

Couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal runtime doesn't provide such an option.

Building report bursting functionality (by page or by group logic) is fairly complex.  Your question seems to suggest you are not very familiar with the Crystal Reports object model.  So consider 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of such tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched). And several of them support report bursting.

Some of these tools also provide an option to export the report to PDF and burst the PDF by page, by bookmark, or by hidden tag formula. That approach may be easier for you to implement in your own code.